# Deserialize cdata inside an Element tag

Tags: c#, deserialization, cdata

New to deserialization and I'm trying to deserialize a RSS feed and its giving an error on the Description CData field when reading in the xml file.  Not really sure how to handle cdata inside an element tag.  Thanks for any help on this...

Example Data feed

```
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>Elite: Dangerous Galnet News</title>
      <link>http://www.elitedangerous.com/galnet/rss</link>
      <language>en-us</language>
      <item>
         <title>Federal President Declares Plant an Illegal Narcotic</title>
         <description><![CDATA[Federal President Declares Plant an Illegal Narcotic

         The Federal President Jasmina Halsey, has declared the newly discovered rare narcotic ‘Onionhead’ illegal throughout Federal space. Onionhead is the fruit of an alien plant, only grown on Panem  in the independent Kappa Fornacis system.  Halsey has said she is concerned by the effect it is having on Federal youth in that part of the Galaxy. "We must be strong and protect our youth from vile substances that are rotting their minds. This is why I have taken this difficult step."]]></description>
         <pubDate>Thu, 16 Dec 3300 00:00:00 UTC</pubDate>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>Slave Rebellion in Sorbago</title>
         <description><![CDATA[Slave Rebellion in Sorbago 

         Rumours of the slave rebellion in the Sorbago system have been confirmed. In a speech to business leaders, pro-slavery Senator Zemina Torval denied sending two of her personal Majestic Class Interdictors, the Boudica and the Elizabeth, to put down the revolt, but said "They have gone to Sorbago to help the local mining corporation keep the peace and to keep out the external forces that are trying to create a conflict".  Reports suggested the slaves are not being treated according to Imperial Law. Torval has announced generous payments to those that help her, and has criticised the barbaric treatment of unregulated slaves outside the Empire in the past. "I will personally sponsor any unregulated slaves brought to Synteini, Shinigami, Quile, LTT 9810, Tau-2 Gruis A, Naunei, and Tepertsi to be given full Imperial Rights and treated as Imperial Slaves."]]></description>
         <pubDate>Thu, 16 Dec 3300 00:00:00 UTC</pubDate>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>Farmer’s Leader Accuses President of Victimisation</title>
         <description><![CDATA[Farmer’s Leader Accuses President of Victimisation    

         Georgio Algeria, the spokesman for the Farmer’s Union in the Kappa Fornacis system has spoken out at the Federal President’s declaration that Onionhead, the main export from the Kappa Fornacis system, be illegal.  At a press conference on Panem he said “Onionhead is great, cool. Loved across the galaxy. We make it, you eat it. Don’t eat it if you don’t want it. Call yourself President! We will keep making it and you will keep eating it. It’s what we do. It’s all we do.”  Algeria would not be drawn on it in public, but it is clear the President's controversial actions have spread publicity for Onionhead far and wide and demand is higher than ever on the black market.]]></description>
         <pubDate>Fri, 17 Dec 3300 00:00:00 UTC</pubDate>
      </item>
      </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is the code I'm trying to deserialize:

```
    #region Galnet News

    public static rss RSSFeed = new rss();

    #region classes

    [Serializable]
    public class rss
    {
         [XmlElement("channel")]
        public List<Channel> Channel { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Channel
    {
        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("item")]
        public List<RSSItems> RssItems { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class RSSItems
    {
        private DateTime pubDate;

        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("description")]
        [XmlText]
        public string Description { get; set; } 

        [XmlElement("pubDate")]
        public DateTime PubDate 
        {
            get { return pubDate; }
            set
            {
               pubDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value.ToString());
            } 
        }

        public bool Read { get; set; }

    }

    #endregion


    public static List<Channel> Galnet_Serialization_Read(string path, bool loadDBFromFile)
    {

        try
        {
            RSSFeed = new rss();

            var reader = new XmlSerializer(RSSFeed.GetType());

            // Read the XML file.
            var file = new StreamReader(@path);

            // Deserialize the content of the file into a Book object.
            RSSFeed = (rss)reader.Deserialize(file);

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error: " + error.Message + " File: " + @path);
        }

        return RSSFeed.Channel;

    }
```

Also tried this replacement with no success ..same error:

```
        private string description;
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public XmlCDataSection Description
        {
            get
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                return doc.CreateCDataSection(description);
            }
            set
            {
                description = value.Value;
            }
        }
```

Here is a link to the actual XML file:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20107089/GalnetNews.xml

Comment: "its giving an error" isn't very specific. What error?

Comment: Error Message: There is an error in the XML document (13,7)

Comment: For which characters you need CDATA in the description, do you try to escape them instead of using CDATA ?

Comment: Its not my data feed to change... I'm just trying to read what there sending posted at the top.

Comment: Do you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364335/problem-with-serialization-deserialization-an-xml-containing-cdata-attribute
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397085/net-xmlserializer-deserialize-cdata-being-inner-text

Comment: none of those examples seem to resolve the issue for the description field.